# Error Building openssl on VS2010

Tags: c++, openssl

It is having problems during linking what file am i missing?

> Visual studio 2010 error output

- Error  14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
  ___umoddi3   C:\Users\Yohannes\Desktop\AES Encryption\libcrypto.a(bn_word.o) Rijndael
- Error  11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __alloca  C:\Users\Yohannes \Desktop\AES Encryption\libcrypto.a(sha512.o) Rijndael
- Error  12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __alloca  C:\Users\Yohannes\Desktop\AES Encryption\libcrypto.a(err_prn.o) Rijndael
- Error  15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___udivdi3 referenced in function _fmtint C:\Users\Yohannes\Desktop\AES
  Encryption\libcrypto.a(b_print.o)    Rijndael
- Error  13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___umoddi3 referenced in function _fmtint C:\Users\Yohannes\Desktop\AES
  Encryption\libcrypto.a(b_print.o)    Rijndael
- Error  10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __alloca referenced in function
  _OPENSSL_isservice   C:\Users\Yohannes\Desktop\AES Encryption\libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)    Rijndael -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to : http://aluigi.freeforums.org/post4997.html

```
link it to libcrypto.a, it's the static library.

if you don't have it:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm
```

Comment: @Preeta I installed gnuwin from the link, added the additional include directories, added additional library directory, added libcrypto.a and libssl.a and now other error messages are displayed. Can you take a look at it please?

Comment: There is some more info here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/ddf0cb80-e841-436d-9ad5-4fa6457e562e